# probability question regarding independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I want to ask a simple probability question and check if my solution is ok.
Not asking for answers, but I want to know which concept of probability theory should be used to solve this problem below.

Problem:
party X, party Y, and party Z received 34%, 42%, and 24% of the votes, respectively. After the election, 7 people are randomly selected. Then, what is the probability that 4, 2, and 1 of them had voted for the parties X, Y, and Z, respectively?

I simply thought that (4/7)*34% would be the probability that 4 of them had voted for party X.
But I think that it's not that simple ...
How can I approach this question ?

Comment: Call the people $a,b,c,d,e,f,g$ – they won't mind, they're used to this sort of treatment. Can you work out the probability that $a,b,c,d$ voted $X$, $e,f$ voted $Y$, and $g$ voted $Z$? Can you see what you have to do to account for the fact that it might have been some other set of four people who voted $X$ and some other set of two who voted $Y$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there were two parties $A$ and $B$, with probabilities of being voted for being, say, $54$% and $46$%, and you wanted to find the probability that $4$ out of $10$ of a random sample had voted for $A$

You know that the answer using the binomial distribution is $\binom{10}4*0.54^4*0.46^6$

Let us write it in a slightly different way,$\;\dfrac{10!}{4!6!}*0.54^4*0.46^6$
indicating the probability that $4$ voted for $A$, and $6$ for $B$

By a simple extension of this concept, the ans to your problem will be

$\dfrac{7!}{4!2!1!}*0.34^4*0.42^2*0.24^1$

This is known as the *multinomial distribution*

Comment: OP wanted an *approach*, you gave OP a complete solution.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: The idea wasn't to spoon feed an answer, but to show a simple transition from a binomial distribution to a multinomial distribution.